# Adding data to a drop down list right in a cell

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I want to make drop down cells in a column L with options from the list Table1 and opportunity to add new items to the source Table1 right through the drop down cell. The following code works fine if the source list is on the same sheet. But I need to have a source table on another sheet.

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(12)) Is Nothing Then
 If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
   If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1"), Target) = 0 Then
      lReply = MsgBox("Do you want to add name  " & _
                     Target & " to the list", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
      If lReply = vbYes Then
          Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").Cells(Range("Tabel1").Rows.Count + 1, 1) = Target
      End If
   End If
 End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Is this inside a Worksheet_Change event in sheet 1?

Comment: Do you mean the code itself? Yes, it is in the object Sheet1

Comment: And it is part of the worksheet_change event?

Comment: Oh, yes Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: If you are about that. I'am sorry, I'am a complete dummy in VBA, can only google and modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Not really sure what you want in the end but this will check items you add in sheet 1 column L and if not present in table 1 will add them as a new row to the table.

Note:

1) Fully qualify range each time

```
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").Range("Table1").Rows.Count + 1, 1)
```

And

2) Spell the table the same way each time so either Table1 or Tabel1.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lReply As String

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(12)) Is Nothing Then 'L

        If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1"), Target) = 0 Then

            lReply = MsgBox("Do you want to add name  " & Target & " to the list", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

            If lReply = vbYes Then

                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").Range("Table1").Rows.Count + 1, 1) = Target

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```